# jQuery select the parent of a div

Tags: jquery, html, parent-child

**I have this html:**

```
    <div class="vt ddsitem">
        <a href="url"><img class="pt" id="xyz1" src="url"></a>
        <div>
            <img class="updown" src="images/updown.gif">
            <a href="url"><img class="bin" src="images/bin.gif"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="vt ddsitem">
        <a href="url"><img class="pt" id="xyz2" src="url"></a>
        <div>
            <img class="updown" src="images/updown.gif">
            <a href="url"><img class="bin" src="images/bin.gif"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And i want to remove the vt ddsitem div in which in the image xyz2 is a child.

**Tried a lot of things, like:**

```
$('#xyz2').parent().parent().remove();
```

but none of them did the trick.

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: The code you've supplied works fine as far as I can tell.  You need to provide the context that the code is in, because you're probably doing something to break it elsewhere.  For instance, are you putting your code in $(document).ready()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is a good method to do what you're after:

```
$('#xyz2').closest('.ddsitem').remove();
```

Though, what you have *should* work, if it's running in a `document.ready` handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#xyz2').parent().parent().remove(); 
});
```

[You can see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/z9GPm/), the same `document.ready` wrapper goes for the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method above...the elements need to be ready and in the DOM before we can find them with a selector.

Comment: closest() was the solution! Strange indeed that the one I used didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be ok.

Are you using any jQuery plugin? If you do, it must be wrapping your div or transforming your code. Try to use [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) to view what happening.

Comment: Yes i'm using this one http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Jquery-Drag-And-Drop-Sort/, Nick's suggestion with closest was the solution!